# Mobile Menu Double Click Problem

Tags: megamenu

Hello guys I am new to Magento system. I have a question. On my website when a user wants to click menu and submenu item he needs to tap on mobile phone two times. I want it to toggle when he clicks one time. Can you help me about this problem?

Comment: check the event which called on one click and two click, also check console error if there is any js error?